# CSS slide page up animation- element briefly shows before the animation

Tags: css, css-animations

I have this CSS animation where when a page is chosen, the page scrolls from the bottom to the top.

The issue I am having is that the page briefly displays in it's top position first, then disappears to scroll from the bottom to top. How can I keep the page from showing before it's animation?

Note: I would like to keep the brief animation delay 500ms

```
mainPanelContent.classList.add('slide-up-now');
```

---

```
.slide-up-now {
  -webkit-animation: slide-up .6s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 500ms;
  -moz-animation: slide-up .6s  cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 500ms;
  animation: slide-up .6s  cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 500ms;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide-up {
        0% { -webkit-transform: translateY(100%); }
        100% { -webkit-transform: translateY(0); }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Solution:**

The correct solution to this issue is to set  `animation-fill-mode` as `backwards` (or use the shorthand like below):

```
animation: slide-up .6s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 500ms backwards;
```

**Reasoning:**

When delay is added to any animation, its execution is put on hold till that time has elapsed and during this time, the element holds whatever position was assigned to it initially.  For it to start at the translated position, you either have to manually add the setting to the element (or) tell the UA to do it for you.

When we set the `animation-fill-mode` as `backwards`, the UA automatically sets the property value defined for the first frame of the animation's first iteration as the properties during the delay period and thus it will start at the translated position for your case.

> Here's what the [W3C Spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-animations/#valdef-animation-fill-mode-backwards) says about `animation-fill-mode: backwards`
>
> During the period defined by animation-delay, the animation will apply the property values defined in the keyframe that will start the first iteration of the animation. These are either the values of the from keyframe (when animation-direction is normal or alternate) or those of the to keyframe (when animation-direction is reverse or alternate-reverse).

**Alternate Solution:**

You can of-course solve this by adding a `transform: translateY(100%`) to the element originally also but that makes less sense when there is a specific property to achieve it.

<sup>(*I assume that the element did not have `transform: translateY(100%)` initially in your code.*)</sup>

**Why using opacity may not always be acceptable solution?**

Solution by using `opacity` (as you have done in your own answer) is not wrong but you would notice that the `opacity` also gets animated from `0` to `1` over the course of the animation which means that the content slowly fades into view as opposed to just a slide up action. While, this can also be fixed by adding extra keyframes in between, those are just work-arounds for something that could have been achieved by using a single property.

**Sample for all solutions:**

In the below snippet, I have added samples for the version with the problem and all possible fixes.

```css
.slide-up-now {
  animation: slide-up .6s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 500ms;
}
.slide-up-now-fixed { /* preferred method */
  animation: slide-up .6s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 500ms backwards;
}
.slide-up-now-fixed-initial-prop {
  transform: translateY(100%);
  animation: slide-up .6s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 500ms forwards;
}
.slide-up-now-opacity {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: slide-up-opacity .6s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 500ms forwards;
}

@keyframes slide-up {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

@keyframes slide-up-opacity {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(100%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

/* Just for demo */

div{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class='slide-up-now'>Slide Up Now</div>
<div class='slide-up-now-fixed'>Fixed by Fill Mode</div>
<div class='slide-up-now-fixed-initial-prop'>Fixed by Initial Setting</div>
<div class='slide-up-now-opacity'>Fixed by Opacity</div>
```

Comment: `backwards` wouldn't work for me when I tried the same set up as `slide-up-now-fixed`. I am using `polymer` framework and I suppose this may create a anomaly. Regardless, I will choose this as the answer. Excellent information.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting @dman. Not disputing your claim but I'd love to see it in action (a link if possible) to see what's going wrong. Btw, thanks for accepting the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I got it with this:

```
.slide-up-now {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: slide-up 1s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 500ms forwards;
}


@-webkit-keyframes slide-up {
        0% { -webkit-transform: translateY(100%); opacity: 1 }
        100% { -webkit-transform: translateY(0); opacity: 1  }
}
```

Note: I did `opacity: 1` twice on purpose. I don't want any opacity effect at all and the first opacity 1 was not enough.

Comment: Opacity twice is a good alternate too. I didn't think of that when I mentioned about extra keyframes in my answer.

Comment: I can't understand why I needed to place `opacity: 1` on the last frame(frame 100%). It seems like the first `opacity: 1` on frame 0% would of been enough.

Comment: That's because when you don't set it, the animation proceeds to the final state (which is the no animation state) and that has `opacity: 0`.

Comment: Can I understand why you've changed the acceptance after such a long time?

Comment: This is actually what I used. But it has been so long I didn't realize I gave you the accepted answer..... I changed it back.

Comment: Not a problem @dman. I just wanted to see if my answer actually broke something in a newer version or something like that. If you aren't comfortable leaving the tick mark on my answer then please feel free.